# PHP - How to store user's preference (Mobile or full site) without using Cookies

Tags: php, session-variables

I need to be able to load the user's previously set preference (within the same session, doesn't have to persist between sessions) of if they want to view the mobile version or full version of the site.

I would like to achieve this via a cookieless approach, however I am pretty sure that storing stuff in the $_SESSION variable will write to a cookie.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Thank you!

Xavier.

Comment: The data saved to $_SESSION does write to a cookie. It writes to a file on the server. What is written to the cookie is a session id. PHP can use this session id to find the file on the server. Then it opens the file on the server, unserializes the data back into an array and then you have access to $_SESSION.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn But it still generates a (session-id-containing) cookie on the client side.

Comment: isn't that what I just said? `What is written to the cookie is a session id.`

Comment: @JonathanKuhn Yes, but he said: "NO cookies" - not "No DATA in cookies".

Comment: @dognose but I was just making sure that OP understood that session data isn't written to a cookie, just the session id is. `I am pretty sure that storing stuff in the $_SESSION variable will write to a cookie` is ambiguous in that they might mean the data from $_SESSION is written.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn it's unclear there, you right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable cookies for the session:

```
ini_set('session.use_cookies', 0);
ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 0);
ini_set('session.use_trans_sid', 1);
```

this will force any client to append his session-id to every request he makes in order to authenticate. (Well actualy your server will append it to any generated link, so the client includes it automatically)

However, this has several drawbacks:

- The session could be "copied" to other clients, when the url containing the session id is transfered.
- Closing the browser and reopening it does reset the session.
- Navigating away from your website may list a valid session id in the "referer" of another server - which might show it somewhere, so any unknown person might get access to the (maybe still valid) session.

Answer (score 0):

First of there is 2 kinds of cookies.

1. The dreaded client cookies.
2. The sessions cookies. A session cookie is only a unique hash set by the server to identifiy the users session (not the user!), you could achive the same thing by adding a query parameter to every link on the site with a number for the session.

The $_SESSION variable contains the variables you set on the server linked to the users session.

You can disable the session cookie and only use query parameters in php.ini